# How to reinstall python

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, python3

I messed up my python3.4 installation by make install of python3.5.

```
$ python3 --version 
Python 3.5.0
```

This is what I get from pip --version:

```
$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)
```

I would like to completely remove python3 and then reinstall it.

Please help. It might be better if I could install python3.5 properly.

Running: elementary OS Freya

Comment: If you still have the Python 3.5 source, you could do `make uninstall`

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall your python using :
`sudo apt remove --purge python3`

And then install python again using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5 python3.5-dev
```

However, not sure if this solves your problem, since it seems you have issues with your pip3, you might need to reinstall your pip3 as well.

In that case, after removing your pip3 using `sudo apt remove --purge pip3`, you can reinstall it using:

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python3.5
sudo easy_install pip
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to mess up with the python installations ...

What you can do is call pip3 for a specific version of python, in your case:

```
python3.5 $(which pip3) install <some_package_...>
```