# Reinstall Python and Python2 on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, python

I had a problem with my Python installation on Arch Linux and that made me wonder if there is any way to reinstall Python and Python2 on Arch Linux.

My guessing is that I should not do something like:

```
pacman -Rns python python2
```

So, is it safe to just uninstall Python and Python2 and then install them again? Or is there a safe way to do this?

I searched and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244702/how-to-reinstall-python), which states that:

> Better not to mess up with the python installations ...

Does this mean that I cannot reinstall Python?

Comment: Your other question is still open and I see no point in this one here.

Comment: @JuliePelletier This question is more out of curiosity and no matter the outcome of the other question, I still would like to know if there is a way to reinstall Python on Arch Linux. I updated my question.

Comment: You can, but the warnings are justified since Python is used by the package manager.  So if anything gets messed up, you won't be able to use the `pacman` to solve it.

Comment: I'm not an Arch user, but I have a suggestion: if you cannot use pacman because you somehow uninstalled python, maybe you can reinstall using something like Anaconda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by reinstalling. To just reinstall:

```
pacman -S python python2
```

If you mean purging from the system, then reinstalling, `pacman -Rns python python2` will likely not work because you will have packages depending on those. If you still want to do this, you can but to be on the safe side:

1. Be sure your system is up-to-date (`pacman -Syu`).
2. Download the python packages to be sure they are in cache: `pacman -Sw python python2`.
3. Close any running application.
4. Exit your session if you’re using a WM or DE.
5. Log into a TTY, stop all services that are not required.
6. Run `pacman -Rddn python python2`.
7. Run `pacman -S python python2`. You’ll likely want to specify `--asdeps` too.

That being said, this whole process is unlikely to bring anything more than the first, way more safe, command.